# How to configure cargo test with custom arguments in VSCode

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

I have some tests which create/read/write/delete a file and I always use the same file name in each of them, therefore I need to run them sequentially to avoid simultaneous operations on the same file. In the command line I can just do it like this

```
cargo test -- --test-threads=1
```

however in the VSCode Run/Debug menu it doesn't seem to work. I'm using the autogenerated configuration with Rust Analyzer, plus these extra arguments for the sequential run.

This is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'my-project'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=my-project",
                    "--package=my-project"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "my-project",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'my-project'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin my-project",
                    "--package my-project",
                    "--", // here I've added the arguments
                    "--test-threads=1", // here I've added the arguments
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "my-project",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the output I get when running the second command (the one which calls `cargo test`):

```
Running `cargo test --no-run --bin my-project --package my-project --message-format=json -- --test-threads=1`...
error: Found argument '--bin my-project' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

    Did you mean '--bin'?

    If you tried to supply `--bin my-project` as a value rather than a flag, use `-- --bin my-project`

USAGE:
    cargo.exe test --no-run --bin [<NAME>]

For more information try --help
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode uses a two steps process:

1. it calls `cargo test --no-run` to compile the test executable and
2. it calls the test executable directly.

You should put `--test-threads=1` in the last `args` array:

```json
{
    "type": "lldb",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'my-project'",
    "cargo": {
        "args": [
            "test",
            "--no-run",
            "--bin=my-project",
            "--package=my-project",
        ],
        "filter": {
            "name": "my-project",
            "kind": "bin"
        }
    },
    "args": [ "--test-threads=1" ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is why it didn't work. Perhaps you also know if there's a way to make the VSCode test UI use this config as well? Either it doesn't work or there's something else wrong because now the tests are stuck infinitely.

Comment: What's the difference between these `args` options?? The `--test-threads=1` is also a cargo argument right?

Comment: @jaques-sam no, the `--test-threads=1` is a _test harness_ argument. The test harness can be run from `cargo` and in that case you can give the option to `cargo` and it will simply pass it along to the test harness. But VS Code only uses `cargo` for compiling and then calls the test harness directly, so you need to tell VS Code to pass the option when it calls the test harness.